# Google charts not working when I use CONCAT() function

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have a google chart displayed on my webpage which is displaying data from a my sql database.

**Here is the query I am using:** 
"SELECT students.firstname as Student, count(attended) as Attended FROM attendance, students 
 where students.studentNumber= attendance.studentId AND students.classGroup LIKE 'ITM4B%' GROUP BY attendance.studentId"

**Here is what the chart looks like:** [image: chart1]
***What I want to change is I want to add the surname to the firstname, but when I use concat, no chart seems to show.***

**This is the statement that I have used with concat:**
SELECT concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) as Student, count(attended) as Attended FROM attendance, students where students.studentNumber= attendance.studentId AND students.classGroup LIKE 'ITM4B%' GROUP BY `studentId`

Someone please help??

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this would work if you wrote the query correctly:

```
select concat_ws(' ', s.firstname, s.lastname) as Student, 
       count(a.attended) as Attended 
from attendance a join
     students s
     on s.studentNumber = a.studentId 
where s.classGroup like 'ITM4B%'
group by concat_ws(' ', s.firstname, s.lastname);
```

This uses proper `JOIN` syntax and fixes the `GROUP BY` so it matches the `SELECT` columns (this could make a difference).

However, I speculate that the real issue may be the length of the resulting names, which affects the charting.